# Error in function "int() argument must be a string"

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms, django-views

I have issues with the following code in my Django project.
Anyone one have a clue what's wrong?

Exception Type: TypeError at /tasks/2/3/ Exception Value: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'DeferredAttribute'

(Django 2.1)

```
def step_detail(request, task_pk, step_pk):
    user = request.user
    steps = Step.objects.filter(task_id=task_pk)
    step = get_object_or_404(Step, task_id=task_pk, pk=step_pk)
    next = ""
    if int(Step.step_number) < len(steps):
        next = "/%s/%s/" % (task_pk, int(step_pk) + 1)
        user.userprofile.current_step.update(step_pk)
    else:
        next = "/task_done/"
        user.userprofile.current_step.update(step_pk)
        user.userprofile.daily_task_done_time(datetime.datetime.now())
    if request.POST:
        if "nextstep" in request.POST:
            return redirect(request.POST.get('next'))

    return render(request, 'dailytask/step_detail.html', {'step': step})
```

> Environment:
>
> Request Method: GET Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/tasks/2/3/
>
> Django Version: 2.1.1 Python Version: 3.7.1 Installed Applications:
>   ['django.contrib.admin',  'django.contrib.auth', 
>   'django.contrib.contenttypes',  'django.contrib.sessions', 
>   'django.contrib.messages',  'django.contrib.staticfiles', 
>   'dailytask',  'account'] Installed Middleware:
>   ['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware', 
>   'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware', 
>   'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']
>
> Traceback:
>
> File
>   "/Users/iamsuccessful/eb-virt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py"
>   in inner
>     34.             response = get_response(request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/iamsuccessful/eb-virt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     126.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)
>
> File
>   "/Users/iamsuccessful/eb-virt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py"
>   in _get_response
>     124.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
>
> File
>   "/Users/iamsuccessful/eb-virt/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py"
>   in _wrapped_view
>     21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
>
> File "/Users/iamsuccessful/ebdjango/dailytask/views.py" in step_detail
>     60.     if int(Step.step_number) < int(len(steps)):
>
> Exception Type: TypeError at /tasks/2/3/ Exception Value: int()
>   argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not
>   'DeferredAttribute'

Comment: What are the "issues"? What problem do you face?

Comment: Put an explanation of the problem in the question, not just the title. Add a full traceback of the error.

Comment: What is the value of `Step.step_number`? I suspect it should be `step.step_number`.

Comment: The error message is on a line that looks like `if int(Step.step_number) < int(len(steps)):`. That line doesn't appear anywhere in the code you posted.

Comment: There's no need to call `int()` around `len()`, since `len()` always returns an integer.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this is just a simple typo, `Step.step_number` should be `step.step_number`.

Comment: Thank you very much! It was the Step.step_number should be step.step_number